# UITableView does not fill out entire screen on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have added an `UITableView` to `Main.storyboard` without setting any additional attributes. On the iPhone the table fills out in the portrait as well as in the landscape mode, the complete screen, which is the desired behavior. However, when starting the app on an iPad, the table looks like this:

[image: iPad UITableView]

When I add the following constraints to the table view:

- Leading Space to Container Margin
- Trailing Space to Container Margin
- Vertical Spacing to Top Layout Guide
- Vertical Spacing to Bottom Layout Guide

The issue is fixed on the iPad (portrait & landscape mode), but on the iPhone the first cell in the landscape mode is hidden:

[image: iPhone UITableView]

How can I fix this? This issue does not occur in the portrait mode on the iPhone, nor does it happen on the iPad in both modes.

BTW, the controller attribute "Adjust Scroll View Insets" is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the inset please add this below code

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
    [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}

if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    [tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}

if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
}
```

For making the tableView fit in all devices so it fits in the whole screen add the below shown constraints.

[image: Constraint]

The resulting TableView will be

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you so much! Adding the constraints you showing in the first screenshot was enough though.

Comment: Welcome Mate, Enjoy coding